# Another beginner with a mysqli issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm quite new to working with PHP and databases. So, like all beginners, I'm having problems with the mysqli extension. I was trying to avoid using mysqli_results, as I didn't want to deal with an array and a loop every time I want a simple piece of data. But that might not be possible.

I need to echo `$user_count`, but nothing seems to be stored there. My code seems to be okay according to the API, but maybe I'm just trying to use the wrong functions altogether. How do I put the result I need into `$user_name`?

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `wp_users` WHERE 1");
$result_user_count = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `wp_users`");
$user_count = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result_user_count, 0);
echo $user_count . ' users found on ' . $dbname . ':</br>';
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Put your full code? and also try to add error reporting then only you will get what error are occuring.

Comment: The beginner mistake here is using `mysqli` over `PDO`. By trying to eschew arrays you've picked the wrong function as well. `_field_direct` does not return result data, but table/column meta information.

Comment: @mario maybe you're right. I might start looking into PDO. And thanks for pointing that out about field_direct

Comment: @umka no error. I think it's technically correct, I think I'm just using the wrong functions and arguments so it's not storing any useful information. I don't know though.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh that's really the only code immediately dealing with the variables I want. I figure if I could get it right here, the rest of it will be pretty easy to replicate. And the full code is too long to bother posting here anyway.

Comment: @Chris_topher please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your provided code, you need to change it like below:-

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS COUNT FROM wp_users") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "Total Users Are:- ". $row["COUNT"];
}
```

Note:- try to add `mysqli` error reporting code so that you will what problem actually exist in your query code, and you can easily resolve them. thanks

Comment: Thanks @anant, I changed the statement to
$user_count = $row["COUNT"];
and it's working fine. I'll repeat this for my other queries. As for errors, I turned on the display_errors in MAMP's ini.php, but I guess that's not really helping me much.

Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. comment if not worked.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS COUNT FROM wp_users");

if ($u_count = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    while ($res = $u_count->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Total Users: ". $res["COUNT"];

     }
}
```

Comment: two time executing query and also one time procedural approach and second time object oriented approach. your code is total wrong.